# Would it be good for the performance if we avoid to use @font-face of high traffic site?

Tags: performance, css, font-face

Would it be good to for the performance if we avoid to use `@font-face` of high traffic site or it will not make much difference?

Client want to use custom fonts using http://www.google.com/webfonts but if it can make the bad impact on performance then we will go for Web safe fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Using a third party font foundry will slow down the initial load of your page - the browser has to do a DNS lookup, create a new TCP connection, many font foundries rely on piece of js to determine which format font to send to the browser - all these add delay.

Some foundries also don't compress fonts when they could e.g. Typekit doesn't compress .eot fonts, they also tend to have very short expiry times for fonts.

There's a good article with a comparison between Typekit and Google Fonts here - http://www.artzstudio.com/2012/02/web-font-performance-weighing-fontface-options-and-alternatives/

On a recent site I was reviewing Typekit was adding 0.5s to initial page load, but as with everything 'your mileage may vary' so you should test and measure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's definitely some extra 'burden', but with proper handling (e.g. [font compression](http://www.phpied.com/gzip-your-font-face-files/)) it'll probably matter... less. It's still gonna be something *extra*, huh?

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to use the web fonts API and include fonts hosted by Google, then Google is going to feel the heat, not you. You'll only have to worry about how long it takes to load these fonts. If you use ten web fonts from Google, that will add considerably to your load times. But it still won't cost you any extra bandwidth, of course, because Google is paying for all of that.

Comment: -1 As per @AndyDavies "How expensive is this request to my server?" is only relevant in as far as it affects the speed with which the user can interact with the web page. To that end, this will slow down the site regardless of who is paying for the bandwidth.

Comment: Sure, but then why he specifies he's interested in knowing this "for a high-traffic site" is a mystery to me. What AndyDavies and you have described applies equally for a site that gets only one hit a year.

Comment: True. I guess the high traffic is relevant in the sense that it matters, whereas lag on a site with one user every year is not really an issue.